# WebGL calculating the vertices on GPU for many identical objects?

Tags: javascript, optimization, webgl

Let's say I have a simple 2d x-y graph. I want to draw a really complicate shape centered at (5,5), (3,4) ,(-1,9), etc.

I know where the vertices of the shape will be relative to a center (n,m). Is it possible to calculate all the vertices on the GPU instead of in javascript? I would just need to upload the relationship of the vertices to the center once and then after that just the individual points.

For example if the shape was a square, the relationship would be:

At the point (n,m), there are vertices (n-1, m-1), (n+1, m-1), (n+1,m-1), (n+1, m+1).

That way I could just upload (5,5), (3,4) ,(-1,9) to the GPU instead of calculating 12 vertices and uploading.

**Questions:**

1. Is this possible?
2. Would this be faster than calculating the vertices in javascript?

Comment: I know this question is old but... it is totally possible to calculate vertices on the GPU. [See this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-without-data.html). You can supply random access arrays of data in textures [see this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-gpgpu.html)

Answer (score 1):

These are some solutions for OPENGL, WebGL does not support apparently.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawArraysInstanced

**edit: Apparently WebGL doesn't have drawArraysInstanced**

Comment: I believe glDrawArraysInstanced will not be available until WebGL 2.0 is.